# Move webSPELL users to Joomla

Tags: database, joomla

I am seeking for a way to move my existing webSPELL userbase into a joomla one.
Is there any way to do this ? Maybe just with a simple sql script ? I only would like the users, mail and passwords to be moved, the rest won't matter.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is a CLI script for importing users. You can modify the script for situaiton.
https://github.com/elinw/AddUsersFromTable

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But How do I use this ? I replaced some informations in that script so it should be okay to work with webSPELL, but I have no clue how to run this :/

Comment: I think it's pretty well documented in the comments that are in the file. Do you know how to get to your command line?

Comment: Not at all, I am running the website on a debian VPS (joomla), but I don't really get how this works. I read that this needs to be in the cli joomla folder, and thought this would just kinda autoexecute or something like that. Unfortunately it doesn't, what do I need to get in the CLI ? Is that just an SSH session ?